# URL modificada al ejecutarse

Tags: phpstorm

Al ejecutar un archivo php desde phpstorm carga el contenido en el navegador correctamente pero al final de la URL le aumenta una especie de código lo cual hace ver sucia la URL, quiero que la URL se cargue como se debe no se que tengo q configurar en phpstorm o usar xampp.

Versión de phpstorm 2020.3

Versión de php 7.4
[image: como se observa en la imagen la URL es modificada al final]

Comment: Busca por rutas amigables, consiste en modificar el .htaccess por ejemplo, para ocultar toda esa información y mostrar la ruta de forma más amigable, por ejemplo en tu caso: http://localhost/TresCapas/CapaPresentacion/Categoria/Elemento (siendo elemento la categoría filtrada)

Answer (score 2):

*Traducción de la respuesta originalmente dada en inglés y que aparece a continuación.*

Este sufijo `#` en la URL es el resultado de unas correcciones de seguridad que evitan accesos no autorizados a recursos albergados en webservers built-in (es decir, aquellos que sirven ficheros desde `localhost:63342`). Puedes leer [Security update for IntelliJ-based IDEs v2016.1 and older versions](http://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2016/05/11/security-update-for-intellij-based-ides-v2016-1-and-older-versions/) <sub>en inglés</sub> al respecto. No hay manera de deshabilitar este sufijo.

Nótese que si debugas desde PhpStorm (a través de las acciones run/debug), la página es autorizada automáticamente, por lo que no se le añade este sufijo.

Si no te gusta que se añada este sufijo, sugiero que uses Xampp u otro servidor web para albergar tu applicación.

---

This `#` URL postfix is a result of security fixes that prevent unauthorized access to resources hosted on built-in webserver (the one the serves files from `localhost:63342`). See http://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2016/05/11/security-update-for-intellij-based-ides-v2016-1-and-older-versions/. There is no way to disable it

Note that if you debug the page from PhpStorm (via run/debug actions), it is authorized automatically, thus no postfix is added.

If you don't like this postfix being added, I'd suggest using Xampp or another web server of your choice for hosting your app.

Comment: Es raro que alguien conteste en ingles una pregunta en español... El sitio tiene como lenguaje obligatorio el español... si no contestas en ese idioma, tu respuesta sera borrada....

Comment: OK, if you can't use Google translate and prefer wrong answers in Spanish to the right ones in English, feel free to delete by answer:)

Comment: No es lo que prefiero.. Es que el idioma del sitio es el español, y las preguntas y respuestas deben estar en español... Para preguntas y respuestas en ingles, hay un sitio al respecto...

Comment: I will not delete your answer, because you are an official voice in this subject.. but we need to translate it... even if you do it with google translate... I will take the case to meta.. I don't want anyone to interfere with this answer...

Comment: We are discussion this answer here: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4979/324.. we would love to hear your voice there too!!!

Comment: gente: los votos no deberían ser más que por la calidad de la respuesta. Votar negativamente porque está en inglés no tiene ningún sentido